# ASP Classic page not displaying correctly when processing several table rows

Tags: asp-classic

My asp page is trying to display several table rows from a loop. Somehow the html output becomes malformed. I'm thinking this might be an issue with asp page processing too much data? I remember back then we would have issues in formatting when rows get to around a few thousands.

Comment: Why not include an example of the code or the malformed output?

Comment: We meed to see an example of it, please show the loop that generates the table

Comment: basically i can no longer find the html, and body html tags when i check the page source. weird because when the rows aren't that many, html output doesn't break

Comment: Still, show Us an example of both cases and the source that generates it, or every thing will be pure guesses.

Comment: And use the edit funtion to update the quer when you do so  ;) Not comments or repost.

Answer (score 1):

Does the portion of data that come from database contain HTML markup? For example you might be doing this:

```
...
<tr><%= rsData( "content" ) %></tr>
...
```

If the `content` field contains HTML markup, specially something like `</td>` or `</tr>` it'll break your table layout.

Comment: If this is the case, you should use <%= Server.HTMLEncode(rsData("content")) %> instead.